# mysql select not does not work

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to only  select student IDs that do not have a row where product ID is 11. But I can't. What should I do?

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE STUDENTS(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, name text,year_born integer 
);

CREATE TABLE PROJECT(project_id integer,title text,project_owner 
text,year_written integer );

CREATE TABLE PROJECTWORKS(student_id integer,project_id integer);
INSERT INTO STUDENTS VALUES(1598,'james',1996);
INSERT INTO STUDENTS VALUES(2479,'andre',1996);
INSERT INTO STUDENTS VALUES(3682,'pierre',1997);


INSERT INTO PROJECT VALUES(10,'A','ABC',2008);
INSERT INTO PROJECT VALUES(11,'B','ABC',2010);
INSERT INTO PROJECT VALUES(12,'C','ABC',2016);
INSERT INTO PROJECT VALUES(13,'D','CBA',2014);


INSERT INTO PROJECTWORKS VALUES(1598,10);
INSERT INTO PROJECTWORKS VALUES(1598,11);
INSERT INTO PROJECTWORKS VALUES(1598,12);
INSERT INTO PROJECTWORKS VALUES(3682,12);
INSERT INTO PROJECTWORKS VALUES(3682,13);
INSERT INTO PROJECTWORKS VALUES(2479,12);

SELECT * FROM STUDENTS;
SELECT * FROM PROJECT;
SELECT * FROM PROJECTWORKS;

SELECT DISTINCT student_id FROM PROJECTWORKS
WHERE not project_id=11 and (project_id=10 OR project_id=12 OR 
project_id=13);
```

I just want **3682** and **2479** Because **1598** has 11.

Comment: Nothing in your code is called `product_id`.

Comment: Do mean not 11? I don't see any with product ID = 14?

Comment: Instead of `x=1 OR x=2 OR x=3` consider expressing it as `x IN (1,2,3)`.

Answer (score 1):

NOT EXISTS is perfect for this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT student_id
FROM PROJECTWORKS p
WHERE project_id IN (10, 12, 13)
AND NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 1
 FROM PROJECTWORKS p2
 WHERE p.student_id = p2.student_id
 AND p2.project_id = 11);
```

Also, I assume you meant you don't want ID 11, as I didn't see 14 in your example.

Comment: yeah 11 but if I want not 11 and 10 what sould I do

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT student_id
    FROM PROJECTWORKS p
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1
     FROM PROJECTWORKS p2
 WHERE p.student_id = p2.student_id
     AND p2.project_id = 14) and (SELECT 1
     FROM PROJECTWORKS p2
     WHERE p.student_id = p2.student_id
     AND (p2.project_id = 10);

Comment: Don't do it like that - put the additional filter in the main query, as I have it above

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, this is what you want

```
SELECT DISTINCT student_id FROM PROJECTWORKS
WHERE student_id not in
(select student_id from PROJECTWORKS where project_id=11)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a join between the two result

```
 select distinct student_id
 from PROJECTWORKS  p
 where  project_id NOT IN (11) 
 INNER JOIN  (
     Select distinct student_id
     from PROJECTWORKS 
     where  project_id IN ( 10, 12, 13)
 ) T on t.student_id = p.student_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT student_id FROM PROJECTWORKS
WHERE student_id not in
(select student_id from PROJECTWORKS where project_id=11)
```

Your question is not clear. above code snippet is for distinct student_id which does not have project_id as 11